# Legacy ASP Pages not functioning correctly in Chrome (Menu dropdown)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a legacy Intranet site developed about a million years ago (I'm not a web developer) - we have set our default browser to Chrome rather than IE recently and we have just learned that this old Intranet site wont function correctly in Chrome. The pages displays, but the menu drop downs just wont display, you click on the menu and the drop down just doesn't appear.

Link to full code: https://github.com/RobAJHopkins/LegacyIntranet/blob/master/Home-Test.asp

```
DIV ID="DepartmentsSpecialistPracticeGroupsmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 160px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('DepartmentsSpecialistPracticeGroupsmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('DepartmentsSpecialistPracticeGroupsmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr>
<td width=160 bgcolor="gray" style="border-bottom: 1px white solid; border-right: 1px white solid; color: white; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Departments</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/worksite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:905:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Corporate</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:903:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Banking & Financial Services</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:906:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Litigation & Dispute Resolution</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:907:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Pensions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:908:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Private Client</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:1238:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Property</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:910:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Tax</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width=160 bgcolor="gray" style="border-bottom: 1px white solid; border-right: 1px white solid; color: white; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Specialist Practice Groups</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td onClick="location.href='practice.asp'" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin; border-right: groove thin;">Click here for Full Listing</td>
</tr>
</table>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="Committeesmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 141px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('hrmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('hrmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:967:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Management Committee</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:964:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Policy Committee</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:970:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Professional Practices Committee</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:968:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Administration Committee</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/social/newsite/index.htm';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Social Committee</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:971:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Charities Committee</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="Extranetsmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 141px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:1713:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Extranets</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="Marketingmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 140px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('Business_Development_Marketingtmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('Business_Development_Marketingmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://algportal/businessservices/BDMKT/Pages/default.aspx';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Marketing Home Page</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>


<DIV ID="HumanResourcesmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 141px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('hrmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('hrmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:339:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Introduction</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='/hr/newsletter/default.asp'" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Newsletters</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:339:&tabid=item-7';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">HR Forms</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:339:&tabid=item-15';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Vacancies</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="InformationTechnologymenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 140px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('itmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('itmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:340:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">IT Department Personnel</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:340:&tabid=item-4';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">IT Training/Keystone Manuals</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:340:&tabid=item-1';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Helpdesk & Operations</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>


<DIV ID="Accountsmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 141px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('accmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('accmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<!-- <tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:361:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Accounts Personnel</td></tr>
-->
<tr><td style="cursor: default; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Under Construction</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="GeneralServicesFacilitiesmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 140px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('facmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('facmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:362:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Safety Information Guide</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/GeneralServices/meetingroomplan.pdf';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Meeting Room Plan</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>

<DIV ID="OtherLinksmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 141px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none" onMouseOver="showBox('otherlinksmenu_menufull');" onMouseOut="clearBox('otherlinksmenu_menufull');">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">

<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/employeemanual/Exigent/ExigentCribSheet.pdf';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Exigent - Guidelines</td></tr>

<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/employeemanual/socialmedia.pdf';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Social Media - Guidelines</td></tr>


<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://www.bankofireland.com/ALGoodbody';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Bank at Work</td></tr>

<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/employeemanual/secondment.pdf';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Secondment Info</td></tr>

<tr><td onClick="location.href='/JuniorAchievement/A&LGoodbody2011.pdf';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Junior Achievement</td></tr>


<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://intranet/services/noticeboard/default.aspx';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Noticeboard</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/WorkSite/scripts/home.aspx?page=!nrtdms:0:!session:dms1:!database:MAIN:!page:778:';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Gym</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/offers/ALG&Renault.pdf';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Renault Service Offer</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://algs.stems.ie/';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Flowers</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='/imanagelink.asp?497374:1:MAIN';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">Croline Rota</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='/imanagelink.asp?330666:1:MAIN';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">GSL Company Distrib. List</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/club/The%20Club%20Directory%202012.pdf';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; border-bottom: groove thin;">The Club Directory</td></tr>
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://worksite1/general/fooddrink/booklunch.asp';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Book A Client Lunch</td></tr></table>



</DIV>
<DIV ID="Noticeboardmenu_menufull" CLASS="submenu" STYLE="width: 141px; background-color: lightgrey; display:none">
<table border=0 width=100% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style="border-top: groove thin; border-left: 1px white solid; border-right: groove thin; border-bottom: groove thin; font: 8pt arial;">
<tr><td onClick="location.href='http://www.employeesfirst.ie/resources/';" onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='navy'; this.style.color='white';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='black'; this.style.backgroundColor='lightgrey';" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px;">Wellness at ALG</td></tr>
</table>
</DIV>
```

Comment: A strong probability is a JavaScript error. Can you show the code for the "showBox" and "clearBox" JavaScript functions, please? And also any related CSS stylesheets. Also examine the browser's Developer Tools (press F12 in Chrome) to look for any errors in the Console section which occur when you try to use the menu. The HTML on its own is not enough info for us to tell you what's going wrong. If you're not confident doing the debugging in the Dev Tools then you'll have to get a web developer who knows what they're doing to look at it.

Comment: P.S. What version of IE was it running in? It would also help if you could share more of the page in particular the `DOCTYPE` and `<head>` sections. A lot of legacy pages like this set themselves to run an IE compatibility mode to to emulate some ancient, non-standards-compliant version of IE, so even if you think it works in, say IE11, the page might be partying like it's IE8

Comment: Thanks for reply, here is the link to the full code, too long to paste on here: https://github.com/RobAJHopkins/LegacyIntranet/blob/master/Home-Test.asp

Comment: @ADyson IE 11 - thanks for this useful information, I have added more information to the original post and a link to the full code set: https://github.com/RobAJHopkins/LegacyIntranet/blob/master/Home-Test.asp

Comment: Thanks. The JS code which contains the menu functionality is not is in the main file. I would suspect it is in the separate files which get incorporated into the page by these two lines of code: `<script language="JavaScript" src="includes/scrolldetails.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="includes/menudetails.js"></script>` so we'd need to see those files, especially the latter one, but seeing both would be good for completeness. And if you can possibly look for errors in the browser console as I described that would really help to narrow it down.

Comment: Thanks again - I have uploaded those .js files to here: https://github.com/RobAJHopkins/LegacyIntranet/tree/master

Comment: Thanks. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RobAJHopkins/LegacyIntranet/master/MenuDetails.JS doesn't look right. That's not a JavaScript file. I'm not sure what it is, to be honest. Are you sure you captured the right thing? It looks like it might be some sort of log file. The functions for the menu are definitely not contained in the scrolldetails file (which looks fine, btw) so they must be in the real version of menudetails.js.

Comment: The only other possibility is that utils2.asp (included in the script via `<!--#include file="includes/utils2.asp" -->` has some JavaScript blocks embedded in it which might contain the relevant functions. Remember we're looking specifically for functions called showBox and clearBox. In the Javascript their definition will start something like `function showBox(` and `function clearBox(` respectively.

Comment: Thanks - sorry for all the back and forth. I have updated the MenuDetails.JS file (sorry I copied the wrong content before and wasn't paying attention) - and I have also added utils2.asp file https://github.com/RobAJHopkins/LegacyIntranet/tree/master

Comment: Sorry, are you able to capture the generated HTML as well? I was trying to make an example to reproduce the problem but without an ASP server to hand it's not easy because a lot of the HTML is generated by script. Load the ASP page in Chrome in the normal way (as if you were using the intranet) and then to Ctrl-U to open the View Source page. This will show you the final HTML including all the bits generated by the ASP script. Copy that into a file in your Github and that will make it much easier to work out the issue, as it's definitely a client-side problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i have done that now: https://github.com/RobAJHopkins/LegacyIntranet/blob/master/Home-Test-SourcePage.asp

Comment: Thanks. In all honesty, this is a horrow show of invalid/broken HTML, missing functions, legacy code and monstrous overcomplexity (probably to get round the browser limitations at the time it was written...or just because the developers thought they were clever). It's basically just showing a few links and an RSS feed from what I can see. I'm not sure I've managed to reproduce the layout properly, there seems to be some style info missing, either that or it's because not all the JavaScript will run.

Comment: Anyway I think it might actually be easier to just get someone to re-write the page in a modern way rather than trying to pick it apart. In the meantime you might have to tell people to use Internet Explorer for the intranet, or delay your switchover (it should have been tested beforehand, to be frank!) till the new version is ready. I get the impression it's mostly just this page which is the ASP, and all the links just go to other sites or applications. It could potentially be fixed but it's not simple to figure out. Certainly it's bit too complicated to tackle just for 15 points on here!

Comment: Thanks and I totally agree. It’s a mess. We are going live with a new intranet site based on SharePoint in a couple of weeks but this current home page is the starting point for employees to access the various resources. I’m not a true developer so I didn’t want to go messing around with anything until I knew more about it. Thanks for taking a look got me, I appreciate it.